# Problems with UNION MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

This works good but now I would like to join a third table, called "houses". But only if `houses.owner` is equal to `p.id`. If there is no `houses.owner` equal to `p.id` dont select.

Current SQL that works

```
-- Select player AND if he is member of a guild then get rank and guild
SELECT p.id, p.account_id, p.group_id, p.name, p.sex, p.level, p.vocation, p.town_id, p.lastlogin, p.comment, p.deleted, p.online, p.rank_id, gr.name AS rank, g.name AS guild
      FROM players p 
      INNER JOIN guild_ranks gr ON gr.id = p.rank_id 
      INNER JOIN guilds g ON g.id = gr.guild_id 
      WHERE p.name = :name and p.rank_id > 0
      UNION ALL
          SELECT p.id, p.account_id, p.group_id, p.name, p.sex, p.level, p.vocation, p.town_id, p.lastlogin, p.comment, p.deleted, p.online, p.rank_id, '' AS rank, '' AS guild
          FROM players p
          WHERE p.name = :name AND p.group_id < 5 AND p.rank_id = 0
```

I have tried adding:

but it gives me:

```
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Comment: I expect you need to cast your blank strings to the same data type as in the first query.

Comment: Troubleshoot by stripping out all the columns, then slowly add them back in.  Start with a literal `1`, then use `p.id`, then `p.id, p.account_id`, etc. until the query breaks.

Answer (score 0):

p.rank_id, '' AS rank, '' AS guild

Is the issue in the second one.

The first query has 3 columns where that is 2. Add another column and it will work. It seems you need a rank and a guild where you are suppinibg guild with the string as rank